# Abstract characterization of polygonizations

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry

Consider a [polygonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_%28geometry%29) of the plane by convex polygons of a given minimal size that meet edge-to-edge and vertex-to-vertex.

[image]
*<sup>What's the “official” name of such a polygonization?</sup>*

Such polygonizations of the plane induce infinite graphs.

> How can such abstract graphs be characterized?

Somehow like this: “A graph is induced by a polygonization of the plane iff it is infinite, planar, 3-vertex-connected, and *P*.” (The question asks for property *P*, since infinite, planar and 3-vertex-connected those graphs obviously are.)

> Is it true, that the graphs that are
> induced by a polygonization of the
> *sphere* are exactly the [polyhedral
> graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_graph) which in turn are exactly the finite planar [3-vertex-connected graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz%27s_theorem)?

Finally I want to know:

> Can the graphs be characterized that are induced by a polygonization of *any* surface?

<sup>For the record: I asked this question at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246929/graphs-that-polygonize-a-manifold) before but it didn't earn a lot of interest.</sup>

Comment: Do you know the infinite version of Steinitz' theorem?

Comment: No, I don't, can you give me a reference, please?

Comment: I asked because you claimed that the polyhedral graphs are the 3-vertex connected graphs...

Comment: What do you mean by minimal size? Combinatorially minimal or metrically minimal?

Comment: Sorry for not having been specific: I meant metrically minimal (to avoid some "fractal" kind of polygonization).

Answer (score 3):

For the OP's claim re *infinite*polyhedral graphs, the answer is yes, this is true, and a proof is in my paper:

Rivin, Igor. "Combinatorial optimization in geometry." Advances in Applied Mathematics 31.1 (2003): 242-271.

Basically, you can construct a circle packing with any prescribed (three-connected) combinatorics. What you lose when you go from finite to infinite is uniqueness, in a spectacular way: it should be true that one can get the carrier of the packing to be *any* Jordan domain.

Comment: @Igor, thank you very much, I'll try to get your paper. For my better understanding: Is it correct, that the *infinite* planar 3-vertex-connected graphs are induced by polygonizations of the plane as specified above (edge-to-edge, vertex-to-vertex) and the *finite* planar 3-vertex-connected graphs are induced by polygonizations of the sphere (a.k.a. polyhedra)?

Comment: @Hans: that's one way of thinking of it. As for the paper, you can get it on arxiv in some version...

   

Answer (score -2):

Voronoi digram/tessellation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: Are you claiming that Voronoi diagrams, which are a very special sort of polygonization, are relevant to this question?